# segmentation fault -- cant understand the cause of the fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I dont understand the cause of the segmentation fault here.
The code is:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

void add(int a,struct node *lista)
{
    struct node *p;
    p=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));

    p->data=a;
    p->next=NULL;

    while(lista->next!=NULL)       <--- The segmentation fault is here. 
        lista=lista->next;                    
    lista->next=p;

    return lista;

}

int main(void)
{
    struct node *list=NULL;
    list_print(list);

    list=node123();
    list_print(list);

    add(7, &list);
    list_print(list);

    return 0;
}
```

the add function which adds a new node to the end of the list worked perfectly like this on a friends computer and setup. I get segmentation fault. i think the problem is the `lista->next` expression but I don't understand why. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use a debugger like `gdb` on Linux? Did you initialize all fields and local variables? Did you asked the compiler for all warnings and debugging info (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` on Linux)?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that's easy... no. :D

Comment: ahh sorry after posting it i just found the problem....

Comment: You didn't include the code for `node123` which could be the source of the error.

Comment: add(7, &list);
here i shoudnt use & before list and its working

Comment: [Do not cast the return of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 2):

`void add(int a,struct node *lista)`... 2nd parameter is a struct node pointer.

`struct node *list=NULL;` -- list is a struct node pointer.

`add(7, &list);` -- &list is a struct node **; this is incorrect and likely to cause add()'s `while(lista->next!=NULL) to fail its dereference.

Comment: +1 the only relevant answer (while others are true they do not answer the question)

Answer (score 1):

```
p = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
```

This is certainly wrong. You must not allocate memory sized as the pointer itself, but as big as the actual structure. Use

```
p = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

or **even better**

```
p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
```

**[And don't for the love of God cast the return value of malloc().](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)**

Also, you declare `list` as `struct node *`, and your `add()` function also expects a `struct node *` - so it's erronous to pass its **address** to the function. Instead of

```
add(7, &list);
```

write

```
add(7, list);
```

Comment: Why the hint of not casting `malloc` returned value? I'll suggest to *always* cast it....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch because this is not C++. Haven't you read the SO question and answer behind that link?

Answer (score 0):

1 - you have to check if lista is not null before writhin lista->next

2 - There is an error in the malloc : 
`p=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

the size to allocate is the size of a `node`, you allocated the size of a pointer `struct node*`.

3 - `add(7 , lista)` not `add(7 , &lista)` because lista is already a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the address of list, but the funciton takes only a pointer, in order to pass 'list' by reference, You've got to chagne the decliration of add to:

```
void add(int a,struct node **lista);
```

and then use (*lista) instead of just 'list' . ex: (*lista)->next ...

Answer (score 0):

You declared 'add' to not return any type of data (void). but you're returning 'list'. either make the function work on a pointer to a pointer to 'list' (taking **list as a parameter instead of *list). or make it return a list type:  struct list* add(